# Angular (TypeScript) models

Tags: angular, typescript, mongoose

I read a lot of questions here, found some answers, but still have few more questions. Are models or interfaces neccessary ? Can I define them in services instead creating new model.ts file ? Should I match TypeScript model with Mongoose schema ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is not neccessary but this is good practice :) And it make code cleaner. Interfaces make code testable